# Search string - illegal chars in path

Tags: vb.net, string, search

I have this search string.

```
Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.0.2\shares\be\" & functiicomune.numeclient & "\" & r & " " & codnumeric & "*" & "\" & "PROD\", "*" & codnumeric & "*" & "DECOMPOSITION" & "*" & ".pdf")
```

I get illegal characters in path and i dont know why. Can someone provide a hint?

The path on the network is:

```
\\192.168.0.2\shares\be\BERTHOUD\BA 390683 L\PROD\BA390683 L - PP. DECOMPOSITION 160630.pdf
```

The numeclient function code is:

```
Public Shared Function numeclient()
    Dim codclient As String = Form1.TextBox4.Text.Substring(0, 2)
    Dim r As String
    Select Case codclient
        Case "BA"
            r = "BERTHOUD"
        Case "CN"
            r = "CARUELLE"
        Case "TT"
            r = "TECNOMA"
        Case "PR"
            r = "PRECICULTURE"
        Case "KR"
            r = "KREMLIN"
    End Select
    Return r
End Function
```

The r and codnumeric code is:

```
    Dim rgx As New Regex("[^0-9]")
    Dim codnumeric As String = rgx.Replace(TextBox4.Text, "")
    Dim r As String = TextBox4.Text.Substring(0, 2)
```

The textbox4 contains string this form: BA390683 L

Comment: what are the values of these variables? can you post the complete path value?

Comment: posted the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify first your code, and add parenthesis when calling the function :

```
Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.0.2\shares\be\" & functiicomune.numeclient() & "\" & r & " " & codnumeric & "*PROD\","*" & codnumeric & "*DECOMPOSITION*.pdf"
```

and second, check the values which compose the path or extension through your debugger :
`functiicomune.numeclient`
`r`
`codnumeric`

Comment: i checked them. i posted the entire path and code. seems nothing wrong with them.

Comment: I think you should call your function with parenthesis : `functiicomune.numeclient()`