# Illegal chars in path - Directory.GetFiles error

Tags: vb.net, string, search, path, directory

I have this search string.

```
Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.0.2\shares\be\" & functiicomune.numeclient & "\" & r & " " & codnumeric & "*" & "\" & "PROD\", "*" & codnumeric & "*" & "DECOMPOSITION" & "*" & ".pdf")
```

I get illegal characters in path and i dont know why. Can someone provide a hint?

The path on the network is:

```
\\192.168.0.2\shares\be\BERTHOUD\BA 390683 L\PROD\BA390683 L - PP. DECOMPOSITION 160630.pdf
```

The numeclient function code is:

```
Public Shared Function numeclient()
    Dim codclient As String = Form1.TextBox4.Text.Substring(0, 2)
    Dim r As String
    Select Case codclient
        Case "BA"
            r = "BERTHOUD"
        Case "CN"
            r = "CARUELLE"
        Case "TT"
            r = "TECNOMA"
        Case "PR"
            r = "PRECICULTURE"
        Case "KR"
            r = "KREMLIN"
    End Select
    Return r
End Function
```

The r and codnumeric code is:

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("[^0-9]")
Dim codnumeric As String = rgx.Replace(TextBox4.Text, "")
Dim r As String = TextBox4.Text.Substring(0, 2)
```

The textbox4 contains string this form: BA390683 L

Comment: A debugger will point you in the right direction. To make your life easier create the path in a string variable first. Then pass it to `IO.Directory.GetFiles`. Post the result of this string as an edit if the answer isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Actually i can see the issue already. You can't use wildcards `*` in the directory. Instead you'll have to enumerate the directories yourself and build up a list of files that way.

Comment: [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) asked for " the specified directory" you can't put wildcards in it.

Comment: Im an idiot. How do i search in subdirectories then if they require wildcare, as they contain only a fixed value in their name ( wich is the item code from my textbox), the rest is variable?

Comment: Get directories has an overload that takes a search pattern and a boolean to search subdirectories (link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How is this any different to your [last question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716681/search-string-illegal-chars-in-path)